# Why do string datatypes always perform value comparison

Tags: c#, .net, string

I was looking for the difference between  `==` and `.Equals` methods in `C#` and I found that the first one compares the object references, and the second one compares the objects values, except for the string datatypes both `==` and `.Equals()` does a content comparison. I can't really find an explanation for that, is it because the string datatypes are immutable ?

Here's what I want to say

```
object obj1 = "Test";
object obj2 = new string("Test".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(obj1.Equals(obj2) + " " + (obj1 == obj2));

string a = "Test";
string b = "Test";
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b) + " "+ (a == b));
```

Output

```
True False
True True
```

In fact for the first comparison we have two different objects with same value and we got as result True and false, but for the case of string we have true for both comparison

Comment: Are you saying if I create a class with 10 properties, `Equals` will automatically compare those 10 properties with another instance of my class?

Comment: @Joe If you write anything a given way it will hopefully do what you tell it to :) I'm just trying to get a clarification from the OP. It's not really clear where they are getting their assumptions from.

Comment: btw... do NOT assume that "string a" and "string b" are separate objects.  because they are compile-time string literals, they probably are optimized to be the same object, therefore they are the same reference.  (apparently, this option can be turned off).   So, (a == b) is probably successful due to being the same reference, not a content comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't true at all. `==` is an overridable operator, and `Equals` is an overridable method. It's up to the class to define how each of them behaves.

Perhaps you're confusing C# with Java?

If you want to do a reference comparison, use `object.ReferenceEquals`. Everything else is implementation dependant (though note that operator overrides are checked statically, so e.g. `(object)someString == (object)someOtherString` will do a reference comparison, not a value comparison; `Equals` doesn't have this "problem").

Most often, both `==` and `Equals` are designed to give the same answer (though `==` is always stricter about types in the comparison, as mentioned before). This applies double for `struct`s, where a reference comparison doesn't really make much of a sense anyway.

And of course, the compiler doesn't actually do any checks. If I want, I can override the `==` operator to always return `false`. Or to only check some ID for equality. Or to *change* the objects being compared, if you are feeling particularly evil. In the end, it's just a static method like any other (with a few restrictions).

**EDIT:**

To address your edit directly, `string` always performs a content comparison because both its `==` and `Equals` are overriden to perform a content comparison. However, that doesn't mean that it always performs a costly char-by-char comparison - if you look how `string.Equals` is actually implemented, you can see that it tries a few things to avoid the costly comparison:

- If the string is null, they must be different
- If the two strings are reference-equal, they must also be content-equal
- If the two strings don't have the same length, they must be different

You can see the actual by-value comparison method here - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e A simple piece of unsafe code, but manually written code nevertheless. There's no automatic value comparison in .NET (though there's tricks that come close).

Comment: The only relevant fact missing here is that the default behavior, if unimplemented, for *both* `==` and `Equals` is to use a reference comparison for reference types and a bitwise comparison of all fields for structs.  It's also a convention that a type should have the same semantics for `==` and `Equals`, so if one is overridden the other should be, and they should behave consistantly with each other.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it for string object both  == operator and Equals() have been overriden to perform the same comparison

Comment: @MoezRebai Sure, it's pretty simple - `return String.Equals(a, b);` :)

Answer (score 3):

It's because it makes sense.

Java couldn't do it this way because it doesn't have operator overloading, but that's no argument in C#.

This isn't unique to strings, by the way. Any type could overload the `==` operator to do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Any object can override/overload `Equals` or `==`, so they can behave however the library author wants them to behave.